# What is the effect of calling AggressivelyCacheFor(duration) outside of a using statement?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, ravendb

I am trying to enable RavenDB Aggressive Caching in a WebApi application, for a **single** action method within a larger application.

In order to achieve this, I went the route of creating an action filter attribute, which gets the `IDocumentSession`, and in `OnActionExecuting` invokes the method to enable Aggressive Caching for 15 minutes.  Then, in `OnActionexecuted`, I call `DisableAggressiveCaching()` on the same session.

In short, this has resulted in some fairly weird behaviour.  After the action method that uses Aggressive Caching has been called, subsequent requests to other action methods, that do not in anyway rely on the cache (they are making completely different requests), end up getting an `IDocumentSession` where the `AggressiveCacheDuration` is 15mins.  The frequency with which this happens seems proportional to the number of times that the cached action method has been called previously.  I should add, I am using StructureMap for DI, using an `IDocumentStore` singleton, and injecting a HttpContextScoped `IDocumentSession`.  I've confirmed that a new IDocumentSession is being injected each and every request, yet some of them have caching enabled.

Some code to try and elaborate further...

IoC - RavenRegistry

```
var documentStore = new DocumentStore {ConnectionStringName = "RavenDB"};

documentStore.Initialize();

For<IDocumentStore>().Singleton().Use(documentStore);
For<IDocumentSession>().HttpContextScoped().Use(x =>
{
    var store = x.GetInstance<IDocumentStore>();
    var session =  store.OpenSession();
    return session;
});
```

AggressivelyCacheAttribute

```
public class AggressivelyCacheAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private IDocumentSession _documentSession;

    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);

        _documentSession = actionContext.Request.GetDependencyScope()
            .GetService(typeof(IDocumentSession)) as IDocumentSession;

        _documentSession.Advanced.DocumentStore
            .AggressivelyCacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);
        _documentSession.Advanced.DocumentStore.DisableAggressiveCaching();
    }
}
```

The same `IDocumentSession` is then used later in the pipeline to query the database, the results of which are cached.

In subsequent request, on methods where the attribute is not present, the injected `IDocumentSession` has caching set to 15mins.  Why is this so?

The only examples I have seen online are where the session is created, with caching, inside a using statement.  Is that the only 'safe' way to use Aggressive Caching, or is it possible to do what I'm trying?  If so, how?

Comment: I have no idea if this would work, but have you tried disposing your session at Application_EndRequest? Alternately just disable caching in your registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [Ayende's blogging platform code](https://github.com/ayende/RaccoonBlog/blob/master/RaccoonBlog.Web/Controllers/AggresivelyCachingRacconController.cs), you need to have a reference in your filter class:

```
private IDisposable _cachingHandle;
```

Then when you make the caching declaration, assign the result to that:

```
_cachingHandle  = _documentSession.Advanced.DocumentStore
    .AggressivelyCacheFor(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15));
```

Then in your Executed,

```
if(_cachingHandle != null)
    _cachingHandle.Dispose();
```

That should stop the unwanted caching.